# Are the sofa chairs in Tanita's apartment her ex-lovers?

Tags: plot-explanation, 9.99

In the movie, [$9.99](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0790799/), is it just an illusion that Lenny has when the sofa chairs in Tanita's apartment start talking to him about bone removal or were they really Tanita's ex-lovers?

The reason I am asking is after Lenny comes back from his "bone removal operation" he is seen in the same shape of the sofa chair in Tanita's apartment.

Comment: Do you mean Tanita is a supermodel? Or is there a style of apartment in the film referred to as a Tanita?

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway Tanita is a super model and the scene happens in her apartment